# The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large Only in HTTPS

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I can find on StackOverflow but I am still getting the error

> The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large"

**Only in HTTPS** and can't quite seem to figure out how to resolve.

1. i changed the maximum size in binding area

   ```
   maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
   maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
   maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
   ```
2. i changed  system.webServer/serverRuntime /uploadreadaheadsize to "2147483647"

still now i getting the (413) Request Entity Too Large

Comment: Split your entity up into smaller pieces.

Comment: To extend on Amy's comment, using pagination to return your data, which is safer than extending your transfer size to the max limit.